# How to use Google Datastore CompositeFilter with Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When reading data from Datastore as input for a pipeline I am able to create a "simple" query, where I set a filter on a single property like so:

```
Pipeline p = ...
Filter filter = Filter.newBuilder()
        .setPropertyFilter(PropertyFilter.newBuilder()
                .setProperty(PropertyReference.newBuilder()
                        .setName("propertyA"))
                .setOp(PropertyFilter.Operator.EQUAL)
                .setValue(Value.newBuilder().setStringValue("valueA").build())
                .build())
        .build();

Query query = Query.newBuilder()
    .addKind(KindExpression.newBuilder().setName("myKind").build())
                .setFilter(filter)
                .build();
p.apply("read", DatastoreIO.v1().read().withProjectId("myProjectId")
                .withNamespace("myNamespace").withQuery(query)).apply(.....
```

When I tried to apply multiple Filters on the query by concatenating the "setFilter()"-calls, only the last set Filter was applied to the query.

Upon some research I found a CompositeFilter which is supposed to enable the combination of multiple filters. I can build a composite filter, but when i want to set it on the query as a filter, the IDE complains that the types don't match and there doesn't seem to be another method to apply filters.

I managed to use a query with multiple filters by using GQL and can see in the logs that it is transformed into a CompositeFilter. I am not here to complain as the usage of GQL is much nicer than building the queries/filters by hand, but wanted to ask how the composite filter of the library WOULD be used in the context of DatastoreIO.v1().read(....) or if it isn't possible.

I am using com.google.cloud.dataflow/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all/2.2.0

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you edit the post, to include the CompositeFilter that you have tried (and the IDE warns you about)?

Comment: Holy **** I just saw a method on Filter.Builder thats called "setCompositeFilter". Thats going to be the way to go. Then you can set that filter on Query.Builder...
Like stated above, I am now using GQL and am happy with that solution. but nice to know now how it would be done
btw. the CompositeFilter is from com.google.datastore.v1.CompositeFilter

Comment: According to the docs, you can. You can use [CompositeFilter](http://googleapis.github.io/googleapis/java/all/latest/apidocs/com/google/datastore/v1/CompositeFilter.html) `newBuilder` method, and create a filter like the following: 

`Filter composeFilter = Filter.newBuilder() .setCompositeFilter(CompositeFilter.newBuilder().addFilters(filter1).addFilters(filter2).build()).build();`



Filter1 and Filter2 here are filters like the ones you have created. My IDE allows me to do this (I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, last version).

Comment: Yes like I said before, I didn't see that method :-)
Thanky anyways! If you want you can answer and I will accept it

Comment: Posted! :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, you can. You can use [CompositeFilter](http://googleapis.github.io/googleapis/java/all/latest/apidocs/com/google/datastore/v1/CompositeFilter.html) `newBuilder` method, and create a filter like the following:

`Filter composeFilter = Filter.newBuilder() .setCompositeFilter(CompositeFilter.newBuilder().addFilters(filter1).addFilters(filter2).build()).build();`

Filter1 and Filter2 here are filters like the ones you have created. My IDE allows me to do this (I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, last version).